# .htaccess increase PHP memory limit ONLY if global is lower

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I know there's a way to set PHP memory limit in the `.htaccess` file doing it this way:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value memory_limit 1024M
</IfModule>
```

or using `mod_php7.c` instead of `mod_php5.c` there, if running PHP7, not PHP5.

But is there a way (some conditional directive) to do that ONLY if the original `memory_limit` set in the global configuration is lower than the `.htaccess` value? I.e. make sure that the entry in the `.htaccess` file always increases, not decreases the limit?

Comment: that seems some what crazy, whats the user case here?

Comment: The idea is to include a .htaccess file in the repository holding an application meant to be used by different people on their local environments and to make sure that those people that have a lower memory limit get it increased without having to mess with their configuration whereas people with better hardware who set an even higher limit don't have to comment out that line of code.

Comment: you could write to .htaccess with php in an install script. not that i actully like the idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not (directly) possible. However, what you can do is [`auto_prepend`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) a PHP file that does what you want. You can specify this file in your `.htaccess` file and it will be prepended to any PHP file:

**raise_memory_limit.php:**

```
// return_bytes() function directly taken from http://php.net/ini_get
function return_bytes($val) {
  $val = trim($val);
  $last = strtolower($val[strlen($val)-1]);
  switch($last) {
      // The 'G' modifier is available since PHP 5.1.0
      case 'g':
          $val *= 1024;
      case 'm':
          $val *= 1024;
      case 'k':
          $val *= 1024;
  }

  return $val;
}

if (return_bytes(ini_get('memory_limit')) < 1024 * 1024 * 1024) {
    ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
}
```

**.htaccess**:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "./raise_memory_limit.php"
```

This way, you don't have to touch any of your PHP files, and still are able to execute PHP code before your application runs. Note that any global variables and functions you specifiy here will be available in all your PHP files, so watch out for that.

Comment: This is a solution that's easy to apply and doing exactly what I needed. Thanks!